# Running code coverage with Cobertura and Jacoco

Tags: maven, sonarqube, cobertura, jacoco

I have a bit of a problem getting code coverage reports for both Integration Tests and Unit Tests in Sonar for a Maven Plugin project (which uses invoker plugin for the integration tests).

I can't use the default Jacoco coverage tool for the unit tests, as these use Powermock, which results in 0% coverage for classes using that.  On the other hand, I can't find a reliable way to get results for the Groovy-based integration tests without using Jacoco.

So what I need is for Cobertura to produce a Unit Test report, Jacoco to produce an Integration Test report, and for Sonar to be able to read the lot.

I tried using the example here https://github.com/Godin/sonar-experiments/tree/master/jacoco-examples/maven-invoker-plugin-example but eliminating the executions bound to the test phase, but I then get a unit test coverage of '-' in Sonar.  I think the reason for this is that to get this method to work, I need to speicify Jacoco as the core coverage tool for Sonar.

Any ideas on a way round this?  My pom.xml follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.acme.myproj.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>slice2java-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

  <name>Slice2Java Maven Plugin</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/generated*/*.java</sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
          <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.5</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
          <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
          <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
          <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <goalPrefix>slice2java</goalPrefix>
          <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>help-goal</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run-its</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
              <debug>true</debug>
              <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
              <pomIncludes>
                <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
              </pomIncludes>
              <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
              <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
              <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
              <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install</goal>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.3.201107060350</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>com.acme.*</includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>invoker.mavenOpts</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: I've been having the same problem on my project.  I've noticed that the only files that seem to have trouble with the code coverage are the ones that use the @PrepareForTest annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've configure Sonar as

```
 <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
 <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
     ${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-t.exec
 </sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
```

This means you are telling Sonar to ***reuse*** the existing report from ***sonar.jacoco.itReportPath***. If there is no existing report, there isn't any coverage.

In my case, I use Cobertura and reuse its report from *Maven site generation*, using the following configuration properties:

```
<sonar.java.coveragePlugin>cobertura</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
    ${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports
</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
<sonar.cobertura.reportPath>
    ${project.build.directory}/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>
```

I can get the reuse by using the following command:

```
mvn clean install site sonar:sonar
```

I can reproduce your issue by using the following command:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar
```

The coverage is 0%. Since there is no existing report at the ***report path***.

Then please make sure that there is a report named *"jacoco-t.exec"* as specified before executing Sonar.

Since I'm not familiar with JaCoCo and do not know which Maven phase that produces the report file, I would suggest to execute the command like the following:

```
mvn clean test sonar:sonar
```

or

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar
```

or the same as mine

```
mvn clean install site sonar:sonar
```

I hope this may help.